# DBeaver transfer data wizard ignores blobs when transferring between databases

Tags: mysql, hsqldb, dbeaver, data-import

I'm trying to transfer an HSQL database into a MySQL one, whose structure is already created, and all is transfered well excepted blobs, which are purely ignored.
Yet I can export complete tables (with their blobs) in SQL "insert" files, XML files and even CSV files (which are not usable when holding blobs, though).
After some changes specific to MySQL I can also import into the MySQL database a SQL file holding blobs, but it is not really a solution for the complete HSQL database.

Is it a known behaviour, or could I do something wrong ?

I work with the 22.3.0 version of DBeaver and MySQL 8.0.31 (and the 2.7.1 version h HSQL driver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried other transfers :

- from HSL to SQL Server : everything worked fine
- from SQL Server to MySQL : everything worked fine

Finally I made the fransfer from HSQL to MySQL work by checking the "Use multi-row insert" option, in the data transfer wizard. I really don't know why MySQL needed it to get all blobs, but if it works...